# Fluid flow through an orifice

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

Forgive me for my ignorance. What would be the method to determine the pressure a non compressible fluid creates when forced though an orifice? Keep in mind this orifice does not have a constant diameter. I know the volume of fluid, the area squared of the orifice and the flow rate. I'm not a mathematician, any information you can provide will be helpful.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a matter of mathematics. (You'll need to know at least the viscosity of the fluid, too).

Comment: Its blood. forty over one hundred units of millipoise.

Comment: You say you know the area of the orifice, but it does not have constant diameter. That's confusing.

Comment: Related question by someone also called Eric: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127954/2451

Answer (score 1):

According to [*this doc*](http://www.mcnallyinstitute.com/13-html/13-12.htm) flow rate is area times velocity times a correction factor $$Q = AVK$$ where $K$ depends on the orifice geometry, and for blood through a heart valve I suspect it is as large as possible, $1.55$.
($K$ is basically the ratio between the area of the actual flow and the measured area of the orifice - they are not the same.)

Pressure is related to velocity by Bernoulli's equation. My favorite explanation is [*this*](http://www.av8n.com/how/htm/airfoils.html#sec-bernoulli) where pressure essentially boils down to $$1/2 \rho V^2$$ where $\rho$ is density (about 1 for blood).
Then all you gotta do is get the units right.

BTW there's a calculator [*here*](http://www.ajdesigner.com/phporifice/orifice_equation_flow_rate.php).